# Unable to get setup file to "Start" with Visual & Installer

Tags: visual-and-installer

My Inno Setup project is named correct in the IDE:

[image: Visual Studio IDE]

And the Visual & Installer project settings also match:

[image: VI Properties]

As you can see, my installer project is part of several, with **Meeting Schedule Assistant** being my primary project:

[image: Solutions]

Even though I select my build project:

[image: Build Project]

It compiles correct if I choose to build it. But, notice here:

[image: Drop List]

The `MeetSchedAssistInno` project is not listed. As a result, when I try to run it I get the following error:

[image: Error]

So I am getting confused. Why can't I trigger the setup file to start?

Note: I know I can set in the **VI Properties** to run the installer:

[image: VI Properties]

**That** way works (but it forces you to build first). But I should be able to simply start the existing installer like normal (or, it prompt me to build if it is out of date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Launching Setup

**There are spaces** in your path to .exe file and that is the reason why the Visual Studio complains "The system cannot find the the path specified."

Did you rename the project or Solution? Please check twice whether the paths and real file names are good and without spaces.

Inno Setup project **does not** register itself among the **Startup Project** list as the Debugging is at this moment not supported. That is a reason why Visual Studio does not show it with GoogleAuthandSync and OutlookCallIFConsole projects.

You can right click the Inno Setup project and choose **Set as StartUp Project** to add this project temporarily into the list so the **F5 will work**

(Alternatively you can right click the project Debug -> Start new instance. Again: this is not real debugging, just launching the .exe).

[image: StartUp project]

## Conditional Startup

Inno Setup supports:

- Build
- Build and Run

This can also be achieved with **Visual and Installer** by having two configurations. For example:

[image: Configrations]

Then, set the **Run installer** option in the properties as required:

[image: Properties]

This way you can choose build, or build and run, by simply choosing the appropriate configuration.

Comment: If I temporarily set the Inno project as the "start up" project, then I see the "Start" button. When I click it it does indeed build (and if I have set the option in the prperties, run the installer). But why can't it detect if it has to build?

Comment: The spaces are irrelevant. These are fine in VS when you wrap your paths in `"` characters. The issue was that it assumed I wanted to use the startup project file - which ofcourse was not correct. Changing the startup project temporarily fixes it. Then I can run it from tool bar or right-click and start new instance like you say. The annoying thing is that is forces you to build even when no changes have been made.

Comment: I am now happy with this. Inno itself also builds when you click "Run". So this is consistent. All I have to remember is to switch the start up project as you instructed.